# combine two arrays in Javascript/react

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am trying to combine two arrays, i tried this:
const admin_navigation = [...AdminNav, ...initialNav] - not working right its over writing one array
i also tried, 
const admin_navigation = AdminNav.concat(initialNav); - give me an error (TypeError: AdminNav.concat is not a function)
what i am trying to create is one array that combine both arrays into one like the bottom example.

=== Array 1 ===

```
const initialNav = {
  items: [
    {
      name: "Test Page",
      url: "/test/testpage",
      icon: "icon-drop",
    },
    {
      name: "Test Page2",
      url: "/test/testpage2",
      icon: "icon-drop",
    },
  ],
};
```

=== Array 2 === (comes from my reducer)

```
const AdminNav = {
  items: [
    {
      title: true,
      name: "ADMINISTRATOR22",
      wrapper: {
        // optional wrapper object
        element: "", // required valid HTML5 element tag
        attributes: {}, // optional valid JS object with JS API naming ex: { className: "my-class", style: { fontFamily: "Verdana" }, id: "my-id"}
      },
      class: "", // optional class names space delimited list for title item ex: "text-center"
    },
    {
      name: "Forms",
      url: "/base/forms",
      icon: "icon-puzzle",
    },
  ],
  //loading: false,
};
```

i need the results to be like this:

```js
const NewNav = {
  items: [
    {
      title: true,
      name: "ADMINISTRATOR22",
      wrapper: {
        // optional wrapper object
        element: "", // required valid HTML5 element tag
        attributes: {}, // optional valid JS object with JS API naming ex: { className: "my-class", style: { fontFamily: "Verdana" }, id: "my-id"}
      },
      class: "", // optional class names space delimited list for title item ex: "text-center"
    },
    {
      name: "Forms",
      url: "/base/forms",
      icon: "icon-puzzle",
    },
    {
      name: "Test Page",
      url: "/test/testpage",
      icon: "icon-drop",
    },
    {
      name: "Test Page2",
      url: "/test/testpage2",
      icon: "icon-drop",
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Look into [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: I think spread operator resolves. `[...arr1, ...arr2]`

Comment: i tried....const admin_navigation = [...AdminNav, ...initialNav] - not working right its over writing one array

i also tried, const admin_navigation = AdminNav.concat(initialNav); - give me an error (TypeError: AdminNav.concat is not a function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initialNav` and `AdminNav` are objects, not arrays. You want this instead:

```
const NewNav = { items: [...initialNav.items, ...AdminNav.items] };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use spread operator or concat over the arrays:

```
const NewNav = {
    items: [...AdminNav.items, ...initialNav.items]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `concat` function also, which will return the result

```
const items  = AdminNav.items.concat(initialNav.items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat method which basically combines two existing arrays and creates a new one like this:

```
let firstNumbers = [1, 2, 3];
let secondNumbers = [4, 5, 6];
let merged = firstNumbers.concat(secondNumbers);
console.log(merged); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate the objects into an array.

try

`const admin={...NewNav,...initialNav}`